# why is one adapter fill working and not the other?

Tags: c#

in the code below if I pass the date ant the account number directly, as shown in the commented out code, the code runs and the report gets populated. 
If I create two string variables, the population comes back empty. What is the difference?
Thanks
(It's a button using a calendar and a combobox with account number values, creating a report)

```
private void btnComputePositionDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    string Date = monthCalendarAdv1.Value.ToShortDateString();
    string AcctNumber = comboBoxAdv1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    //  this.SpDealRiskDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.BloombergDataSet.SpDealRiskData, "03/26/2014", "1500");
    this.SpDealRiskDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.BloombergDataSet.SpDealRiskData, Date, AcctNumber );
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
 }
```

Comment: Have you debugged and inspected the values of your strings? What are they?

Comment: Why does the dataadapter accept two strings at all? Use the correct types `datetime` and `int` in your sql.

Comment: Tim, the sql is expecting varchar for both in the stored procedure

Comment: @user2321650: why is it expecting varchar if it actually seems to be a datetime and an int?

Comment: AntP, The values displayed from the Watch are : "03/25/2014" and "1500"

Comment: SpDealRiskData '03/25/2014',1500 directly in sql server 
The above works.

Comment: Since the date values are different ie. 25 Mar vs 26 Mar and we have no knowledge of your data, do you expect the SP to return any values for 25 Mar?

Comment: typo I meant 26 Mar in both cases.

Comment: Are both cases being run on the same machine? Concerned with possible different culture settings affecting ToShowDateString

Comment: yes both are on the same machine. Thanks

Comment: Please disregard, the watch was actually showing 3/26/2014 vs 03/26/2014. I think that was the issue. I'll ask again if it wasn't . thanks again!

Comment: Last thing I can think of is maybe "BloombergDataSet.SpDealRiskData". Does this contain the same value during both your cases?

Comment: I answered here since the system wouldn't let me answer this question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks failedprogramming, Tim and Ant P

Comment: FYI, this helped solve the issue. Thanks again guys!
string Date = monthCalendarAdv1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard, the watch was actually showing 3/26/2014 vs 03/26/2014. I think that was the issue. I'll ask again if it wasn't . thanks again!
This solved the issue:
string Date = monthCalendarAdv1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");